# Understanding CComBSTR assignment operators

Tags: c++, string

Say I have the following:

```
BSTR myBSTR = SysAllocString( L"MYBSTR" );
CComBSTR myCComBSTR = myBSTR;
```

Does `myCComBSTR` take ownership of `myBSTR` and free it when it goes out of scope? Or does it make a copy of `myBSTR` and produce a memory leak if i dont free `myBSTR`?

If this produces a memory leak, what's the most efficient way of handling this? (`myBSTR` will be passed in to a function as a `BSTR` and i want to store it as a `CComBSTR`internally)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case the `CComBSTR` instance creates an independent copy.  You will need to manually free `myBSTR` to avoid a leak.

The simplest approach to fix this scenario is to skip the middle man `SysAllocString` function

```
CComBSTR myCComBSTR = L"MYBSTR";
```

On the other hand if you have a `BSTR` and want to have a `CComBSTR` take owner ship of it then use attach method.  This method transfers ownership of the resource from the source `BSTR` to the `CComBSTR` instance.

```
CComBSTR myCComBSTR;
myCComBSTR.Attach(myBSTR);
```

Comment: What is the difference between CComBSTR::Attach and CComBSTR::AssignBSTR?

Comment: @mvdavid7, AssignBSTR does not transfer ownership and just makes a copy.  Attach transfers ownership to the `CComBSTR` and makes no copy.