# Why do I leak memory when using CComSafeArray<BSTR>?

Tags: c++, com

I have a memory leak which I've narrowed down to the following code.  What's going on?

```
CComSafeArray<BSTR> sa(5);
sa[0] = SysAllocString("constant");
```

[`CComSafeArray::~CComSafeArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f97ayy5.aspx) calls `SafeArrayDestroy` (via `CComSafeArray::Destroy()`, see below), which [should then call `SysFreeString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221702(v=VS.85).aspx) on all members.  As such there shouldn't be a leak here.  What's going on?

```
HRESULT Destroy()
{
    HRESULT hRes = S_OK;
    if (m_psa != NULL)
    {
        hRes = Unlock();
        if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
        {
            hRes = SafeArrayDestroy(m_psa);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
                m_psa = NULL;
        }
    }
    return hRes;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Instead of saving a copy of the pointer in the `CComSafeArray<BSTR>`, `CComSafeArray<BSTR>::operator[]` and `CComSafeArray<BSTR>::GetAt(T)` return a `CComBSTR` object which takes a copy of the `BSTR`.  This results in the `BSTR` leaking.

**Long answer:**

After several fruitless hours, a compilation error when attempting to compile a simpler version to try to narrow down the leak gave it away:

```
CComSafeArray<BSTR> sa(5);
sa[0] = nullptr;
```

This won't compile because under the covers `CComSafeArray<BSTR>::operator[]` returns a `CComBSTR` object, and `nullptr` can match both `CComBSTR::operator=(LPCSTR)` and `CComBSTR::operator=(LPCOLESTR)`.  Bam, compilation error.

Once I discovered `CComBSTR` was involved under the covers, it fell into place.  [`CComBSTR::operator=` takes a **copy** of the `BSTR` instead of saving the pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3559990/10247) (how I read the code, given normal behaviours) or taking ownership, resulting in the leak of the unfreed temporary `BSTR`.

```
typename _ATL_AutomationType<T>::_typewrapper& GetAt(_In_ LONG lIndex) { ... }

...

// specialization for BSTR so GetT doesn't return &BSTR
template <>
struct _ATL_AutomationType<BSTR>
{
    typedef CComBSTR _typewrapper ;
    enum { type = VT_BSTR };
    static void* GetT(_In_ const BSTR& t) throw()
    {
        return t;
    }
};
```